# grant read access to non-root user to a mounted bucket

Tags: linux, windows, google-cloud-storage, fuse

I have mounted a bucket to archive old data. My problem is, a non-root user needs access to these files from time to time. Is there any way to grant her read access to this bucket/mount. She uses Windows if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can give her read [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) over the bucket so she can see the files using cloud console, as you are using fuse, locally All files have permission bits 0644, and all directories have permission bits 0755, you can find more information on how to change those fuse permissions [here](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#inodes)